# TypeError: Cannot read property 'watch' of undefined at Runner.run

Tags: webdriver-io

I am using WebdriverIO for automation when the test case is executed, even though all steps are executed successfully, I am getting below error.

ERROR @wdio/local-runner: Failed launching test session: TypeError: Cannot read property 'watch' of undefine d at Runner.run (...\node_modules@wdio\runner\build\index.js:165:15)

Answer (score 0):

How are you starting WebdriverIO? We had encountered the same issue when starting WDIO programmatically using the launcher directly from a script.

When using the launcher from a script (see: https://webdriver.io/docs/clioptions.html#run-the-test-runner-programmatically), make sure to pass the additional options including `args`:

```
const wdio = new Launcher('/path/to/my/wdio.conf.js', { args: [''] });
```

Note the `{ args: [''] }` - leaving that out will cause the error you reported.